# Javascript - Remove values from array - Constructing an array of times

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an issue figuring this out. The idea is that I have an array of values that I'm considering times, and I need to remove all values that overlap with a specific time:

`var availableTimes = ['0 - 0.5', '0.5 - 1', '1 - 1.5', '1.5 -2', '2 - 2.5', '2.5 -3']`

`var timeToRemove = '0.5 - 2'`

I have full control over what the array looks like, but that's the idea. I can't figure out how to construct my array of available times and my `timeToRemove` so that I can accomplish this. I am using a 24:00 hour clock, so `1 - 1.5` is 1:00 AM to 1:30 AM.

Any thoughts on the best way to construct this?

Comment: you'll have to loop on all items and then parse the strings into workable numbers and then check with some logic which returns true or false. I suggest looping the array using `filter` for that -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Show us what the expected result should be after removing the times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer a OO way to do it:

(1) Construct an array with objects with following structure:

```
  {
        StartTime:[fload],
        EndTime:[fload]
  }
```

So your time array looks like this

```
 var availableTimes=
    [
      {StartTime:0,EndTime:0.5},
      {...}
    ];
```

(2) The time to be removed has the same structure:

```
  var timeToRemove = '0.5 - 2';
  =>
  var timeToRemove={StartTime:0.5,EndTime:2};
```

(3) Delete algorithm looks like this:

```
  for (var i=0;i<availableTimes.length;i++)
    {
      if(availableTimes[i].StartTime > timeToRemove.StartTime 
        && availableTimes[i].EndTime < timeToRemove.EndTime)
        availableTimes[i]=null; //perform deletion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have control over your data structures, I think you're better off structuring it as arrays of length 2 than strings (though you can convert what you have to this form by using `split(" - ")`)

```
var availableTimes = [[0,0.5], [0.5,1], [1,1.5], [1.5 -2], [2,2.5], [2.5 -3]]
var timeToRemove = [0.5,2]

for (var i = 0; i<availableTimes.length;i++){
  //use >= and <= if you want a closed interval
  if ((availableTimes[i][0] > timeToRemove[0] &&
       availableTimes[i][0] < timeToRemove[1]) ||
      (availableTimes[i][1] > timeToRemove[0] &&
       availableTimes[i][1] < timeToRemove[1]))
     {
        console.log("overlapping time: " + availableTimes[i]);
     }
}
```

produces:

```
overlapping time: 0.5,1
overlapping time: 1,1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var availableTimes = ['0 - 0.5', '0.5 - 1', '1 - 1.5', '1.5 -2', '2 - 2.5', '2.5 -3']
   var timeToRemove = '0.5 - 2';

   var tempar = timeToRemove.replace(/\s/g,"").split('-');

   for(var i = 0, t = availableTimes.length; i < t; i++){
      var itemar = availableTimes[i].replace(/\s/g,"").split('-');
      if(tempar[0] === itemar[0] && tempar[1] === itemar[1]){
           availableTimes .splice(i, 1);
           return;
      }
   }
```